# Codeigniter Migration Not Loading To Database

Tags: codeigniter

My database migrations are not loading on codeigniter. Not creating table when have setup database.

I have a front end form which I fill out to be able to connect to the database on my install/step_3. But will not load migrations into database even though when click on next button it post the database info to the database.php file. **It has the correct database name and prefix.**

```
Error Number: 1102
Incorrect database name ''
SHOW TABLES FROM ``
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-cms\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Comment: Make sure the database name you're using actually exists.

Comment: it does once I click on the continue button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had to create a new stage so can load migrations because database needed to load first then the migrations. I have got it all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the database name, User and Password